# Why does `ls 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\'` show nothing?

Tags: powershell, ls, recycle-bin, hidden-file

I have a lot of files in Recycle Bin, yet using either `ls 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\'` or `Get-ChildItem 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\'` in PowerShell 7.1.5 there is no result. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` doesn't list hidden files by default. You need to use the [`-Force` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2)

```
$ Get-ChildItem -Force 'C:\$Recycle.Bin'
$ ls -Fo 'C:\$Recycle.Bin'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using WinPS and PSCore. Get-ChildItem has a switch when looking for hidden files.

```
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Keys
# Results 
<#
...
Hidden
...
#>


$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
# Results
<#
Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      2      6
#>

 Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin' -Hidden
# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\$Recycle.Bin

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d--hs           03-Apr-22    17:29                S-1-5-18
d--hs           03-Apr-22    15:24                S-1-5-21-2605158930-3620923046-633914236-1000
d--hs           03-Apr-22    15:39                S-1-5-21-2605158930-3620923046-633914236-1001
d--hs           08-Oct-22    23:56                S-1-5-21-2605158930-3620923046-633914236-1002
#>

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
# Results
<#
Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
5      1      19041  1682
#>

 Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin' -Hidden
# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\$Recycle.Bin

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d--hs           03-Apr-22    17:29                S-1-5-18
d--hs           03-Apr-22    15:24                S-1-5-21-2605158930-3620923046-633914236-1000
d--hs           03-Apr-22    15:39                S-1-5-21-2605158930-3620923046-633914236-1001
d--hs           08-Oct-22    23:56                S-1-5-21-2605158930-3620923046-633914236-1002
#>
```

The -Force works in both as well as already shown.